# Android studio not deleting my items in Adapter?

Tags: android, arrays, android-recyclerview, adapter

```
 public void setSearch(ArrayList<Search> ListSearch){
    search=ListSearch;
    removeInActiveClasses(search);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0,search.size());
}


public void removeInActiveClasses(ArrayList<Search> data){
    for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){
        boolean isActive=Boolean.parseBoolean(data.get(i).getActive());
        System.out.println("The course at Not Removed "+search.get(i).getName()+" is set to "+search.get(i).getActive());
        if(!isActive){
            System.out.println("The course at Removed"+search.get(i).getName()+" is set to "+search.get(i).getActive());
            search.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

A list is passed through as listSearch and it contains a list of courses, if the courses are set to active which is a string that either true or false, and parsed as a boolean, then the item should be removed. I am certain I did the parsing correctly so I am wondering what is going on here? How come it does not delete all the false courses?

Comment: check your isActive, i suspect it is not changing status, check it by Log

Comment: did you try to call notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ all the isActives are set to false intentionally, to test if it will remove all of the classes which it does not

Comment: @SaehunSeanOh yes, I tried that, as well as all the other notify methods lol

Comment: I suggest taking search.remove(i); out side if statement just to be sure that it is not your if statement

Comment: Does it print out `"The course at Removed"+search.get(i).getName()+" is set to "+search.get(i).getActive()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might wanna create another instance of ArrayList and set your `search` to that one because your are accessing and modifying your ArrayList at simultaneously.

Other notes:

Please use `camelCase` for your argument names. So instead of ListSearch, use `searchList`.

For your class variable, try adding `m` in front so you won't get confused. So instead of `search`, use `mSearchList`

Lastly, you are mixing some variables within one method. Try unifying them for better maintenance.

Here's the full code.

```
public void setSearchList(ArrayList<Search> searchList) {
    mSearchList = removeInactiveClasses(searchList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


private ArrayList<Search> removeInactiveClasses(ArrayList<Search> data) {
    ArrayList<Search> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
        boolean isActive = Boolean.parseBoolean(data.get(i).getActive());

        if (isActive){
            list.add(data.get(i));
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: I'm not removing items from passed ArrayList. Instead, I'm adding what's true to a new list, and returning that ArrayList so you can set your `mSearchList`